# open file with a particular regex search

Tags: search, load

Can one associate a regex query with a particular file, so that whenever that file is opened, the query (e.g., `/text`) is run, causing all instances of `text` to be highlighted?  I considered using modelines for this purpose but they only accept option settings.  Is there another mechanism whereby an arbitrary search can be run upon loading a specific file (perhaps through use of `autocmd`s in an adjunct .vimrc file placed in the same directory as the file in question)?

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right path with your `autocmd` hunch. However, this problem is
complicated by `:h autocmd-searchpat` (emphasis mine):

> Autocommands do not change the current search patterns.  Vim saves the current
> search patterns before executing autocommands then restores them after the
> autocommands finish.  **This means that autocommands do not affect the strings
> highlighted with the 'hlsearch' option.**

However, a workaround is then described:

> If you want an autocommand to set the search pattern, such that it is used
> after the autocommand finishes, use the ":let @/ =" command.

So, you could directly manipulate the last used search pattern with `:let @/ = {pattern}`

```
autocmd BufRead {filename} let @/ = '{pattern}'
```

With `{filename}` replaced with your filename, and `{pattern}` replaced with the pattern you wish to search for.

Comment: Thanks, though that does not seem to work for me on vim v8.1.  The search does run but the instances of `{pattern}` are left unhighlighted despite `hlsearch` being set.  Pressing `n` / `N` uses the last manual query, rather than the one in the `autocmd`.  I am able to verify that the search runs when the file is loaded because if I search for text that is not present, `vim` displays an error upon opening the file: `Error detected while processing BufRead Autocommands for "<path>":  E486: Pattern not found: badpattern`.  The effect of the search appears to be discarded.

Comment: Hmm... does using `BufWinEnter` instead work? Maybe you have to search after processing mode lines.

Comment: That also does not work.  I also tried removing the modeline.

Comment: I have edited my answer.